# Script running another script according to start and end date

Tags: shell

I have one script which needs to be run according to month wise. Which means, If startdate is 2016-12-01 and enddate is 2017-03-01 then the first script should run for the period of 4 month.
Can you help me in writing such script.

Comment: Not so clear your question for me. Look at crontab and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell

Comment: you need to study creating crontabs in unix / linux https://corenominal.org/2016/05/12/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/